# How to pass a complex number into an templated array search function?

Tags: c++, class, templates

I am trying to pass a complex number into a templated array search function but I keep getting the error "no matching constructor for  initialization of 'Complex', Complex c_arr[n], c_element;". It also says that the "Complex class required 2 arguments but 0 were provided." Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
# include <iostream>
# include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

class Complex {
    private:
        double re, im;
    public:
        Complex(double re, double im) {
            this->re = re;
            this->im = im;
        }
       // Complex()
        Complex& operator=(const Complex o) {
            this->re = o.re;
            this->im = o.im;
            return *this;
        }
        friend istream& operator>>(istream &i, Complex c){
            i >> c.re >> c.im;
            return i;
        } 
        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &o, Complex c) {
            o << c.re << "+" << c.im << "i" << endl;
            return o;
        }
        friend bool operator==(const Complex c1, const Complex c2){
            if ((c1.re == c2.re) && (c1.im == c2.im)){
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
};


template <class T>
int array_search(T arr[], int n, T some_element){
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        if (arr[i] == some_element)
            return i;
    return -1;        
}

int main(){
    int n;
    cout << "How many elements are in the array?" << endl;
    cin >> n;

    int intarr[n], i,element;
    cout << "Enter elements of the int array: " << endl;
    for (i=0; i < n; i++)
        cin >> intarr[i];
    cout << "Enter integer to search" << endl;
    cin >> element;
    cout << array_search(intarr, n, element) << endl;

    cout << "How many elements are in the array?" << endl;
    cin >> n;

    float flo_arr[n], f_element;
    for (i =0; i < n; i++)
        cin >> flo_arr[i];
    cout << "Enter floating-point number to search " << endl;
    cin >> f_element;
    // passing floating point array to templated function
    cout << array_search(flo_arr, n, f_element) << endl;

    cout << "How many elements are in the array?" << endl;
    cin >> n;

    Complex c_arr[n], c_element;
    for (i=0; i <n; i++)
        cin >> c_arr[i];
    cout << "Enter complex number to search" << endl;
    cin >> c_element;

    /*cout << array_search(c_arr, n, c_element) << endl; */

    cout << "How many elements are in the array?" << endl;
    cin >> n;

    double dou_arr[n], d_element;
    for (i =0; i < n; i++)
        cin >> dou_arr[i];
    cout << "Enter floating-point number to search " << endl;
    cin >> d_element;
    // passing double precision point array to templated function
    cout << array_search(dou_arr, n, d_element) << endl;


}
```

Comment: Note that VLA is not legal in C++ - `double dou_arr[n]`. use `std::vector<double>` instead

Comment: Also, declaring an array of Complex requires that Complex has a default constructor. It also isn't valid unless the compiler supports the VLA extension,

Comment: Since this has been closed, I'll put some general comments here. Just use `std::complex` https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex . Your `istream` operator should take `Complex& c`, otherwise it won't get modified . Use an initializer list in your constructor. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list

Comment: I hope I fixed all problems: https://wandbox.org/permlink/SzItsfMVBBEZhQy7